# Passing one literal variable as well as placeholders in prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am creating a form that will be submitted by the user. In the form submission process, some values are hardcoded in the source code and are inserted as it is. Can I pass these values directly to the prepared statement? Other user input data I am binding that will be replaced with the `?` placeholder.

For example:

```
...
$litVariable = 1;
$userInput   = $_POST['user_input'];
$myquery     = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table(`column1`,`column2`) VALUES('$litVariable',?)");
$myquery->bind_param("s",$user_input);
...
```

Is that ok and safe to pass `$litVariable` directly to query and user-generated input with `$myquery->bind_param("s",$user_input);`, as I did above?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to this, other than realizing that mysqli parameter binding is obtuse?

Comment: You would also need to be sure that any value didn't have any quotes in - which is why it would be *easier* to stick with binding values.

Comment: `You would also need to be sure that any value didn't have any quotes in`, you mean the `$litVariable`?

Comment: It is fine as long as its NEVER user generated, if you have a "type code" for example

Comment: If it is a constant value then why have it in a variable? Just make constant values as part of the SQL without any variable interpolation. If the values are coming from PHP variables then bind them.

Comment: Why do you ask? What is the use case for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you are doing should be safe, because the value `$litVariable` which you are concatenating into the query string does not come from the outside.  This means that the first item in your `VALUES` clause should *not* be prone to injection attacks coming from the outside.  That being said, I would still suggest not even doing this, because it leaves your insert query looking prone to attack.  There is no reason to not use bound parameters everywhere.  That is, I suggest the following:

```
$litVariable = 1;
$userInput = $_POST['user_input'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)";
$myquery = $mysqli->prepare(sql)
$myquery->bind_param("is", $litVariable, $user_input);
```

Comment: But if I am sure that the `$litVariable` is secure than is this approach right according to the standards of prepared statements?

Comment: @StackOverflow The thing is, secure or not secure, if you use a statement, then you can't be injected.  If you _don't_ bind the value as a statement parameter, then you might be open to injection.  At the very least, those who inherit your code later on may be left wondering why you chose to do it this way.

Answer (score -1):

This question is more about psychology than technology.

When your processing is uniform, you don't have to measure every single variable you are working with, considering whether it is secure or not. You will get in return

- faster coding. you don't have to stop and think, how this particular variable is going to be inserted - as is or prepared. For the every single variable.
- no chance for the human error when you can swear that a variable is safe but in reality it is not

To soften the pill, I can offer you a [mysqli helper function](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple) that can make your prepared queries less boring

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(column1, column2) VALUES (?, ?)";
prepared_query($mysqli, $sql, [$litVariable, $userInput]);
```

only two lines of meaningful code versus four lines of repetitive code.